# Excel VBA Run time error 1005=4

Tags: vba, excel, runtime, formula

I am getting a runtime error when running this marco in excel. The code when rows = 1 works perfectly but I get a runtime error after the else. I can't seem to figure out the problem

```
If rows = 1 Then
Sheets("Sales Report").Range("C" & 1 + rows).Formula = "=SUMIFS('Stock Log'!$I$2:$I$1048576,'Stock Log'!$H$2:$H$1048576,B2,'Stock Log'!$B$2:$B$1048576,""<=""&A2)"
Else
Sheets("Sales Report").Range("C" & 1 + rows).Formula = "=SUMIFS('Stock Log'!$I$2:$I$1048576,'Stock Log'!$H$2:$H$1048576," & Cells(rows + 1, 2).Address & ",'Stock Log'!$B$2:$B$1048576,""<=""" & Cells(rows + 1, 1).Address & ",'Stock Log'!$B$2:$B$1048576,"">""" & Cells(rows, 1).Address & ")"
End If
```

Comment: you forgot the `&` inside the formula string change `""<="""` to `""<="" & "` And change the `"">"""` to `""> "" & "`

Comment: Thanks. It's working now.